# Error running multiple kafka standalone hdfs connectors

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

We are trying to launch multiple standalone **kafka hdfs** connectors on a given node.

For each connector, we are setting the `rest.port` and `offset.storage.file.filename` to different ports and path respectively.

Also kafka broker JMX port is @ 9999.

When I start the kafka standalone connector, I get the error

> Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 9999; nested exception is:
>       java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)

Though the rest.port is set to 9100

kafka version: 2.12-0.10.2.1

kafka-connect-hdfs version: 3.2.1

Please help.

Comment: I am seeing this issue only on node where Kakfa-Manager is also running. On nodes, where only kafka-brokers are running, the rest.port option is allowing multiple connectors to work

Answer (score 0):

> We are trying to launch multiple standalone kafka hdfs connectors on a given node.

Have you considered running these multiple connectors within a single instance of Kafka Connect? This might make things easier.

Kafka Connect itself can handle running multiple connectors within a single worker process. Kafka Connect in distributed mode can run on a single node, or across multiple ones.

Answer (score 0):

For those who trying to use `rest.port` flag and still getting `Address already in use` error. That flag has been marked as deprecated in [KIP-208](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-208%3A+Add+SSL+support+to+Kafka+Connect+REST+interface) and finally removed in [PR](https://github.com/a0x8o/kafka/commit/09cec57051971ad0ed37130826c9c70c23c99b52).
From that point `listeners` can be used to change default REST port.
Examples from Javadoc

```
listeners=HTTP://myhost:8083
listeners=HTTP://:8083
```

[Configuring and Running Workers - Standalone mode](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/self-managed/userguide.html#distributed-mode)

Answer (score -1):

You may have open Kafka Connect connections that you don't know about. You can check this with:

```
ps -ef | grep connect
```

If you find any, kill those processes.